# How to return only column value from coalesce operator in mysql query

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have wrote mysql sub query  using coalesce operator but sub query is returning object ,what I want is sub query should return value and based on that sub query value main query will get data

```
Query:

 $var=$this->db->query(" 
 select id
      , prduct_name 
   from product 
  where quantity = 
       ( select coalesce
         (
           ( select min(quantity) as qty 
               from product 
              where qunatity >= '110')
         , ( select max(quantity) as qty 
               from product 
              where qunatity <= '222') 
         )
       )
")->row();
```

if I run only this query :

```
select coalesce((select min(quantity) as qty from product where qunatity >='110'), (select max(quantity) as qty from product where qunatity <= '222') ))
```

Then instead of returning value  it return object. so how to write perfect way sub query with main query

Comment: What is qunatity? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: its column name

Comment: so does this `quantity`?

Comment: So you have two columns with confusingly similar names? Who upvotes this stuff?

Comment: column s have different name  I am just checking condition

Comment: actually I got stuck in this query this didn't work for me